# PHP Upgrade from version 5.1.6

Tags: php

I have a fairly large website that runs on PHP 5.1.6. What concerns should I have if I try to upgrade to the latest version? Are the differences considerable? Should I migrate from 5.1 to 5.2 and 5.2 to 5.3 to minimize the incompatibility issues that might arise?

Thanks,

Comment: upgrade php version 5.3.x and above, is best choice

Comment: It will be the latest version (5.4), but I want to have an input on what is the best approach to take.

Comment: Start by reading the changelog: http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php  there is NO way we can answer this, as we have no idea what your code is like, or if any of depends on things removed/deprecrated from later versions.

Comment: I read the changelog, but the changelog is version to version and I am going from 5.1.6 to 5.4. I didnt want you to look at my code and answer specific questions. I just wanted best approach! I wanted to know what people suggest and wanted to share. If I knew the PHP Community was this HARSH, I would go with my instinct in the first place.

Comment: FYI, Marc B and all the "downgraders", I am getting a new SERVER, copy my current website structure into it, update to PHP 5.4 and test it. Thanks for your effort of clicking the down vote button? It didnt take much!

Comment: I just wanted to pick the GENIUS BRAINS of the PHP COMMUNITY, but what you just did shows me otherwise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are upgrading php, you install the whole package from scratch, i.e new versions are not applied incrementally.

So, you do not need to go from 5.1 to 5.2 to 5.3, upgrade to the desired version directly (I recommend using php 5.4).

The php.net site is also very helpful when doing upgrades, you can see the new features and the changes which are breaking compatibility between versions.

Have a look at the following links:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration52.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.php

In my experience, code created for php 5.1 runs smoothly on 5.4.

The best approach would be to review the changes, setup the site on a development environment,do thorough testing, if everything is ok upgrade in production. Be sure to enable and monitor your server logs in production mode, so that you can catch problems, if any, as they arise.

Comment: Hey Alexander, thanks for the suggestion. I will go ahead an get a new server and do the testing there. Thank you!